# Not able to Calculate JSON expression with String datatype

Tags: java, json

We are using https://github.com/octomix/josson library

JSON

```
{
  "pressureStage":1,
  "data":{
    "flange":{
      "specification":"PN 16"
    }
  }
}
```

JAVA Code

```
String a = "{\"pressureStage\":1,\"data\":{\"flange\":{\"specification\":\"PN16\"}}}";
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(a);
String expression3 = "calc(if(sp==\"PN16\",350*2,400*2),sp:$.data.flange.specification)";
System.out.println(josson.getNode(expression3));
```

Gives Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid function call calc() : Calc syntax error.
    at com.octomix.josson.FuncDispatcher.apply(FuncDispatcher.java:84)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathBySteps(JossonCore.java:328)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathBySteps(JossonCore.java:249)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathByExpression(JossonCore.java:211)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getNodeByExpression(JossonCore.java:147)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getNodeByExpression(JossonCore.java:142)
    at com.octomix.josson.Josson.getNode(Josson.java:279)
    at com.octomix.josson.Josson.getString(Josson.java:535)
    at com.velotech.pumpselection.velotech.expressionCheck.main(expressionCheck.java:25)
```

This code work when the datatype of specification is **numeric**, but gives error when datatype is **String**

Regards,
Pranav

Comment: Are you sure that you can use values from datatype String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside function `calc()`, the first argument uses *MathParser.org-mXparser* library expression syntax. Maybe that is the reason of not supporting **String**.

Please try the following expression instead. It selects the desired value before pass into the *MathParser.org-mXparser* expression.

```
calc(sp*2, sp:$.data.flange.if([specification='PN16'],350,400))
```

For multiple conditions, you can use function `caseValue()`.

```
data.flange.specification.caseValue(
    'PN16 RF', calc(250*2),
    'PN40 RF', calc(250*2),
    'ANSI B16.5 CLASS150 RF', calc(260*3),
    calc(265*4)
)
```

Comment: This would work, but if the expression is longer it will be complicated. Actual expression to evaluate is calc(if(sp=="PN16 RF",250*2,if(sp=="PN40 RF",250*2,if(sp=="ANSI B16.5 CLASS150 RF",260*3,265*4))),sp:$.tbl05FlangeMasterSuction.specification)

Comment: Another way to evaluate is to remove calc function in the start. Like if($.tbl05FlangeMasterSuction.specification=="PN16 RF",calc(250*2),if($.tbl05FlangeMasterSuction.specification=="PN40 RF",calc(250*2),if($.tbl05FlangeMasterSuction.specification=="ANSI B16.5 CLASS150 RF",calc(260*3),calc(265*4)))). But here I have to define $.tbl05FlangeMasterSuction.specification every time in expression. In the calc function We abbreviated sp: $.tbl05FlangeMasterSuction.specification and used "sp" short everywhere. This would shorten the expression string. @Raymond Choi your comments please